# SQL: Determine if a record (First/Last Name) occurs more than once in the Date Column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with **FirstName, SecondName and Date Columns**. A number of records occur more than once in the date field.

```
First_Name  Last_Name  Date

Amy         James      1/1/2011
Amy         James      1/1/2012
John        Jones      1/2/2011
James       Anyone     2/2/2011
James       Anyone     2/2/2012
```

I am trying to query the distinct **First and Last Names** that occur in both 2011 and 2012 only. 
Thanks,
J

Comment: from the example above, what would you need as your end result

Comment: @Jisha Can you show us the end results? And clarify if 2011 and 2012 can have amy, james as long as amy, james has no duplicate records in both years individually?

Comment: @bonCodigo Hi, I am looking for a result that looks like this:      Amy James                                                          James Anyone

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at `GROUP BY` and `YEAR` functions.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT First_Name, Last_Name
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY First_Name, Last_Name
HAVING COUNT(Year([Date])) > 1
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0167b/5).

Comment: Thank you! That works well. Is there a tweak to the query that will ensure the name returned must occur once in 2011 and once in 2012? Appreciate the assistance.